# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow: How to send a person as initiation parameter when started from code

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I am starting a Sharepoint 2013 Workflow via javascript and I want to set one initiation parameter as a person in it.

Here I define my initiation Parameter and start the Workflow. I am using a people picker for the person field. I tried different notations for the person like id, mail, display name, key and json objects.

```
var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;
var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
var initiationParams = {};
initiationParams["Person"] = keys;
initiationParams["String"] = "test";
startWorkflow("name", initiationParams);
```

With this function initiation Parameter can be send when starting a workflow. It works with string parameter.
I got the code from the last anwser of:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175041/trying-to-start-sharepoint-workflow-from-code

```
/**
 * Starts a SharePoint 2013 Workflow on a particular list or library item.
 * https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175041/trying-to-start-sharepoint-workflow-from-code
 * 
 * @param {string} workflowName         The name of the Workflow
 * @param {string} initiationParams     The initiation Parameters of the Workflow
 */
function startWorkflow(workflowName, initiationParams) {

    var itemId = 1;
    var listGUID = "{643fa273-936b-4a21-a602-0589ccafa1b0}";

    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {
        SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.workflowservices.js', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl(
            'sp.workflowservices.js'));
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.workflowservices.js', "SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager",
            function () {
                var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
                    wfsManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx, ctx
                        .get_web()),
                    wfSubs = wfsManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().enumerateSubscriptionsByList(
                        listGUID);
                ctx.load(wfSubs);
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    wfsEnum = wfSubs.getEnumerator();
                    while (wfsEnum.moveNext()) {
                        var wfSub = wfsEnum.get_current();
                        if (wfSub.get_name() === workflowName) {
                            wfsManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(
                                wfSub, itemId, initiationParams);
                            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                                function (sender, args) {
                                    console.log("Successfully started workflow.");
                                },
                                function (sender, args) {
                                    $("#workflowResult").html(
                                        "Fehler beim Starten des Workflows.");
                                    console.log("Failed to start the workflow.");
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }, function (e) {
                    console.error(e)
                });
            }
        );
    });
}
```

How do I send a person via initiation parameters to my workflow via javascript?

Comment: also I just realized, that I could have postet it in sharepoint stackexchange. Should I do that? Do I delete the question here then?

Answer (score 0):

One option you may consider is to pass the SharePoint user ID (UID) as an integer parameter or the email address as a string parameter and then resole it to a person within the first stage of the workflow.